# Git version tag in edit control box visual studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, winapi

I want to include git version tag in my win32 project. It should be seen in edit control box. I am trying to find good information about that but it seems I can't find any. I know it's possible in qt application but I am not sure if it is possible in visual studio. So anykind of information about it would be helpful.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you want to compile the version tag (as a resource or otherwise) into the executable image, and then display it in your application?

Comment: yes, I want to have an option to display it on my application. So i need it in my program as some kind of variable. I can add it as resource or by other means.

Comment: Git doesn't come with keyword expansion out-of-the-box (which is essentially what you're looking for). This needs to be integrated into your workflow. See [Customizing Git - Git Attributes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes) (paragraph on *"Keyword Expansion"*) for details.